# Application compiles in Eclipse, but has 'undefined reference errors' in Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse, qt, undefined-reference

I am building an application that uses mysql and needs a graphical user interface. Because I am more comfortable with Eclipse, and it seems to have better organization and 'pop-up references', I decided to develop the main engine in Eclipse, and transfer it to Qt (using Qt Creator 3.1.2, based on Qt 5.3.1) for the GUI. The engine compiles in Eclipse fine (and a command-line test in Eclipse runs well), but when I include the files in the Qt project, I get undefined reference errors.

I get an error (`undefined reference to 'sql::mysql::get_driver_instance'`) anywhere I have this code:

> sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver* driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance();

I have all the relevant headers included (since Eclipse sees no problem with it):

> #include "mysql_driver.h"
>
> #include "mysql_connection.h"
>
> #include < cppconn/driver.h>
>
> #include < cppconn/connection.h>
>
> #include < cppconn/statement.h>
>
> #include < cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
>
> #include < cppconn/resultset.h>
>
> #include < cppconn/metadata.h>
>
> #include < cppconn/resultset_metadata.h>
>
> #include < cppconn/exception.h>
>
> #include < cppconn/warning.h>

Sounds like a linker error, but I can't find a place to specify linker options in the Qt options page. I'm using the gcc compiler on Ubuntu 14.04.

Am I forgetting to change a setting somewhere or is it something else?

Comment: Is this a compiler/linker error or just a superficial warning from the editor?

Comment: @snowandotherjoys - it says "error", and won't run, and only appears when I select run, so I think it is a compiler/linker error

Comment: You must link with mysql driver library.

Comment: How do I do that in Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, thanks to [this thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/31492-how-to-link-library-in-Qt%28-like-gcc-l-command%29). Rather than linking in an options page, I merely had to edit the Qt project (`.pro`) file. I added the following:

> LIBS += -lmysqlcppconn

And it now compiles and runs fine. So the problem was simply I didn't understand how to do the linking.